# Configuration Errors: Elastic Load Balancer + EC2 + Route 53

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

I am trying to configure my website to have a secure connection (https://) via Amazon's EC2, ELB, and Route 53.

I am running a t2.micro instance (no Elastic IP or anything). My Elastic Load Balancer has the SSL certificate attached. My SecurityGroup allows for https connections through port 443. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

All of my configurations are below. Any help is appreciated because, as it stands, I can't access my website at all.

Thank you in advance!

### EC2 - - -

[image: EC2 Instance]

### Load Balancer - - -

[image: Load Balancer]

### Route 53 - - -

[image: Route 53]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Hit the EC2 instance directly and verify that the health check URL responds with an HTTP 200 status code. If not, then get that working first.

You aren't clear about your security group configuration. You should have a security group on your load balancer that allows HTTP and HTTPS connections. Then you should have a security group on your EC2 instance that allows HTTP (port 80) connections from the load balancer's group.

The issue is obviously the failing health check on the load balancer at this point, so no need to look at Route 53 settings right now. You need to concentrate on getting the communication working between the EC2 instance and the load balancer to get that health check to start working. Until then the load balancer won't accept any traffic because it doesn't have instances it considers healthy that it can forward traffic to.

Comment: The instance is working properly from the public DNS route. The security group on my load balancer and EC2 instance are the same. The allowed inbound requests are: HTTP, PostgreSQL, Custom TCP Rule, SSH, and HTTPS - all with TCP protocol and corresponding port ranges. Is there something I'm missing within the security group protocols?

Comment: Do you have any of those ports restricted? Or are they all open to the world?

Comment: They're all open. I'll change that down the road, but I just wanted to make sure I could get it working first

Comment: I was able to get the instance and the load balancer to communicate. It says its InService, and I am able to visit the load balancer's DNS with no trouble. My Route 53 does not let me visit the custom domain, however. Would you happen to know how to fix that?

Comment: Did you update your name servers at your domain registrar to the name servers provided by Route 53?

Comment: I'm using Route 53 as my domain registrar, so it should be defaulted to the given name servers.

Comment: When did you register the domain then? I'm unable to resolve your domain name.

Comment: I originally purchased it via Google Domains a few months ago. Yesterday, I transferred it into Route 53. It said the transfer was completed on Amazon's site.

Comment: I was able to get it working now. Thank you for your help!